# How can I concatenate a where clause using OR on LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have this code :

```
foreach (Package pack in Packages)
{
    filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(o => o.ID == pack.ID);
}
```

the only problems is that I filter the result N time (so N where). 
What I'd like to do is to filter the result only one time (only a where clause) with N expression. Somethings like :

```
    Where o.ID == pack.ID OR o.ID == pack.ID OR o.ID == pack.ID OR o.ID == pack.ID...
```

Is it possible to do this with LINQ?

Comment: What's the type of `filteredResults`? `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`? And which linq implementation are you using? Linq-To-Objects, ...

Comment: Can you clarify what you'd like? Something can't equal 1 and 2 (assuming that each pack.ID is meant to be different.

Comment: And many implementations already optimize multiple `Where` clauses, so using `AND` is not necessarily much faster than using multiple `Where` clauses.

Comment: I wrong, sorry! Yeah I mean OR... I use IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the code below should work, or at least steer you in the right direction.

```
-- Get all the package IDs you want to select on.
var packIDs = from pack in Packages
    select pack.ID;

-- Return all results where the ID is in the package ids above.
filteredResults = from result in filteredResults
    where packIDs.Contains(result.ID)
    select result;
```

The above assumes your and's were a logic mistake and you meant ors.

Comment: Thank you! This in fact works! I just want to know if was possible to concatenate where with OR :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var packIds = Packages.Select(x=>x.ID).ToArray();
filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(o=> packIds.Contains(o.ID));
```

If this is linq to sql this will get translated into:

```
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help you:

```
filteredResults = originalResults.Where(o => Packages.Any(p => p.ID == o.ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you not want Intersect()? i.e

```
var ids = filteredResults.Select( fr => fr.Id ).Intersect(Packages.Select( p => p.PackID ) )  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use expression with LinqKit

```
var v = from utente in db.Utente
        select utente;

Expression<Func<Utente, bool>> expr = c => c.Age == 26;
expr = expr.Or<Utente>(c => c.Name != "Matteo");

v = v.Where(expr.Expand());
```

The result is:

```
SELECT...... FROM......
WHERE (26 = [Extent1].[Age ]) OR ('Matteo' <> [Extent1].[Name])
```

I have the same issue, i try this solution